# Class variables in private methods

Tags: java

Are there any advantages/disadvantages to passing class variables as arguments to a private method versus simply referencing them? As my classes grow longer and longer I worry about future coders needing to scroll up to the top of the class to figure out what "foo" is so I'm considering passing them as arguments when the method is called, but I'm not sure if that will cause other problems I'm not considering.

In short; is this:

```
public class Foo {

    private int number = 0;

    public Foo(int startingNumber) {
        this.number = startingNumber;
    }

    public int biggerNumber() {
        return embiggenIt(number);
    }

    // ... Many lines of code ...

    private int embiggenIt(int aNumber) {
        return aNumber++;
    }
}
```

Any better or worse than this:

```
public class Foo {

    private int number = 0;

    public Foo(int startingNumber) {
        this.number = startingNumber;
    }

    public int biggerNumber() {
        return embiggenIt();
    }

    // ... Many lines of code ...

    private int embiggenIt() {
        return this.number++;
    }
}
```

... and if so, why?

**EDIT**

Okay so apparently I should specify here that I don't care about changing the class variable, I'm not sure why everyone jumped to that conclusion; I didn't realize my example was that terrible (although I did slap it together in a hurry). In the example all I care about is the return value after I run the method (think functional programming).

Perhaps this is a better example of what I'm talking about:

```
public class Foo {

    private static final int number = 0;

    public Foo() {
    }

    public int biggerNumber() {
        return embiggenIt(number);
    }

    // ... Many lines of code ...

    private int embiggenIt(int aNumber) {
        return aNumber +1;
    }
}
```

v.s.

```
public class Foo {

    private static final int number = 0;

    public Foo() {
    }

    public int biggerNumber() {
        return embiggenIt();
    }

    // ... Many lines of code ...

    private int embiggenIt() {
        return this.number +1;
    }
}
```

I will stress that the variable does not have to be constant, but I added that just to make it clear that I'm not interested in altering the variable (I understand passing by reference vs passing by value, thanks).

Now that we're a bit more clear, does either approach make a difference? Which would you rather read? Which would make you smack the Jr. programmer's knuckles?

Comment: Do you understand that both the codes have different behaviour?

Comment: Please note that a primitive type will be passed _as value_, opposed to an `Object` that will be passed _by reference_. Your first example will _not_ increment the class member.

Comment: @XaviLópez Even Object references are passed by value.

Comment: @RohitJain Indeed. I stand corrected :-)

Comment: I do understand the difference between how each method affects the class variable, I was doing that to get a return value from the function. Sorry for the bad example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured out the answer to me question. It seems that the other folks read my code without understanding the question, but I stumbled upon the correct answer myself.

Passing variables to methods is preferable to simply referencing class variables because it allows us to perform dependency injection when testing. The obvious exception being class constants.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you are passing by value. So the member variable of the class is never modified. In the second case, you are referencing the class variable itself.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is worse as it will only cause you headaches with keeping track of the scopes. For example in your first code the value of the class variable `number` will not increase because you are only increasing the value of the local field `aNumber` which is pointing to a different variable than `aNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your code samples will produce different results - the first one does nothing, while the second one actually increments `number`. Both return the old value of the variable however (i.e. without the added 1), because you use the post-decrement operator `x++` (instead of `++x`).

Secondly using fields is no problem even in big class files if you use self-explaining names.

And thirdly it's often not possible to omit using the field if you want to assign a value back to it.

Answer (score 0):

In java a native type such as int, double,... is passing by value

and any class object's is passing by reference.

so in your code you can use Integer class Instead int